# Equality using OR in RSpec 2

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

What is the correct way to write the following example? The player's score should equal 5 or 8.

```
it "should equal 5 or 8" do
  player.score.should == 5 or 8
end
```

Thanks!

Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5 or 8` will produce result 5 all the time and not do what you expect.  You can use Rspec's satisfy matcher.

```
 player.score.should satisfy {|s| [5,8].include?(s)}
```