# How to use `or` in RSpec equality matchers (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm trying to do something like

```
expect(body['classification']).to (be == "Apt") || (be == "House")
```

**Background:**

This is testing a JSON API response.

**Issue:**

I want the test to pass if either "Apt" or "House" are returned. But in the test it is only comparing to the first value, "Apt".

```
Failure/Error: expect(body['classification']).to be == "Apt" or be == "House"

expected: == "Apt"
got:    "House"
```

**Previous Solution:**

There is a solution here,
([Equality using OR in RSpec 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474726/equality-using-or-in-rspec-2)) but its depreciated now, and I wasn't able to make it work.

**Documentation:**

Also wasn't able to find examples like this in the documentation (https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/built-in-matchers/equality-matchers)

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
expect(body['classification'].in?(['Apt', 'Hourse']).to be_truthy
```

Or

```
expect(body['classification']).to eq('Apt').or eq('Hourse')
```

Or even this:

```
expect(body['classification']).to satify { |v| v.in?(['Apt', 'Hourse']) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(body['classification']).to eq("Apt").or eq("House")
```

Based on this [link](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/compound-expectations#use-<code>or</code>-to-chain-expectations)

"**Compound Expectations**.

Matchers can be composed using and or or to make compound expectation

Use `or` to chain expectations"

```
RSpec.describe StopLight, "#color" do
  let(:light) { StopLight.new }
  it "is green, yellow or red" do
    expect(light.color).to eq("green").or eq("yellow").or eq("red")
  end
```